# transfering Text in text view from listview item from activity to a dialog box

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am tearing my hair out at this and cannot seem to get it working. I have an activity that has a listview, the single row in that list view consist of Three textviews and an imageview. Im trying to take all the text from ONE textview in that single row( just one) and put it in my custom dialog's textview when the item is clicked. Here is one of my attempts: ( the application crashes when i click an item in the listview)

```
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ////Attempting Onclick method \\\\
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                String txt =((TextView)mListView.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                TextView dialogt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
                dialogt.setText(txt);
                confirmEvent();
            }
        });
```

If i were to Toast txt, i get the right response but it never changes when i select a different item in the list. it just stores it forever. 
MY confirmEvent() method is really just the custom method from the android developer website. but let me know if i should post it aswell.

**/////UPDATE////**

Toast works when i change mlistview to view as suggested by corsair992 ( see comments below) but app still crashes when i try to transfer that data to my dialog textview.

below is my custom dialog code:

MyDialogFragment.java

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
 // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogb, null));
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_Event)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.add_to_cal, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   Toast.makeText(MyDialogFragment.this.getActivity(), "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

This is my confirmEvent method which is referencing the class above:

```
public void confirmEvent() {
        DialogFragment mDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "test");
    }
```

**////update///**

logcat data:

02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at com.wordpress.yourhappening.happening.Homepage$ListViewLoaderTask$1.onItemClick(Homepage.java:229)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-26 15:21:39.359: E/AndroidRuntime(746):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Try changing it to to `view.findViewById()` instead of `mListView.findViewById()`.

Comment: Do you use a custom adapter or a simple one ?

Comment: Thank you for your responses, i am using a simple adapter. when i change mListView to view the toast works! the response changes depending on which item in the list i select, just like it should!!!! but... if im trying to send that data to the textview in the dialog it crashes.

Comment: You should update your question and add the exception from your logcat.

Comment: post your custom dialogs code

Comment: Looks like your "dialogt" `TextView` is null...

Comment: but i assigned the string txt to dialogt, and txt is not null. why do you say it is null?

Comment: Yes, and that is why you are getting the `NullPointerException`, I assume. That's the only object referencing that I can see in the `onItemClick()` method, apart from getting the text from the `ListView` item which seems to be working. Really, this is very basic debugging, which you should perform yourself...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.i am still learning android, not pro yet. However, that still does not change the current predicament, i doubt assigning a default value would solve this but i will try that. do you have any suggestions that i may try?

Comment: It looks like you have some issues with your logic. I have added an answer, check it out and see if the suggestions there help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the `TextView` with the "`dialog_text`" id is actually included in the "`dialogb`" layout that you inflate in the `Dialog`. If that is the case, then you should move this logic to the `DialogFragment` where this is implemented.

First you need to pass the text value to the `DialogFragment`. Change your `confirmEvent()` method to accept a `CharSequence` parameter and pass it as an argument to the `DialogFragment`:

```
public void confirmEvent(CharSequence text) {
    DialogFragment mDialog = new MyDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence("text", text);
    mDialog.setArguments(args);
    mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "test");
}
```

Then change the following line in the `onCreateDialog()` method:

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogb, null));
```

to this:

```
View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogb, null);
TextView dialogt = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
dialogt.setText(getArguments().getCharSequence("text"));
builder.setView(content);
```

Or you could just use the `setMessage()` method on the `AlertDialog` builder instead if you only need to set text on the dialog without customization.

Last of all, remove the dialog text setting logic in the `onItemClick()` callback, and pass the text to the `confirmEvent()` method instead.

I haven't tested this code so there may be some syntax errors or other minor issues, but this should provide you with the general idea.

Comment: im am testing this method out, will get back to you.

Comment: IT works !! perfectly!! you are a genius, thank you for all your help. It appears that this one was just too advanced for me, i do not fully understand your code yet, but i just followed your instructions and it worked. thank you. Also i have read that one cannot use the findViewById on a layout that is not inflated in that activity, that was one of my mistakes.

Comment: If i were to change the CharSequence, would this method work just fine with images as well?

Comment: Nice to know that it worked - looks like you corrected my typo in the "text" key :) You can pass image resource ids or `Uri`s or a `Bitmap` in a `Bundle`, but not the `Drawable` itself, so you should probably get whichever one of these that you're using from the original data source of the `ListView` and pass them on, as `ImageView` does not provide an API for accessing them.

Comment: i think i will end up opening a new question for this because i cannot seem to get it working. through my research, the only way i see to pass an image is to pass the bundle through an intent, but im not using an intent for this dialog box. can you be more specific as to how i pass the bundle as it pertains to my current code?

Comment: @crushman: Yes, open a new question on this, along with the details of what you have tried and what is not working, and I'll try to answer it. There is no need to use an `Intent` to pass on the `Bundle` though.

Comment: after working on it the entire day, this was my attempt. didnt work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084529/how-to-pass-image-from-listview-item-to-a-dialog-box-without-the-use-of-an-inten